# Copying data from one column to another for a report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table `MIS_Details`; it has following columns:

- Cheque_status
- Cheque Bounce Date
- Policy_status_change_date

I am creating a report in Excel using a select query.

My requirement is as follows: If the cheque status column has value `'Cheque Bounce'` I need to copy the cheque bounce date of that record to `Policy_status_change_date` but without updating the table in the Database.

This is just to show in the report, so I can't use update.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be able to use a case statement to see if the value in the `cheque status` column matches your text, and if so, use the bounce date as the value of the `Policy_status_change_date` column (syntax may be different depending on the type of database that's providing your data).

```
SELECT 
   ChequeStatus
   ,ChequeBounceDate
   ,CASE 
      WHEN ChequeStatus = 'Cheque Bounce'
         THEN ChequeBounceDate
      ELSE Policy_status_change_date
   END AS Policy_status_change_date
FROM 
   MIS_Details
```

Also, on a design note, you may want to store the possible statuses in another table so that you're just using a status ID to compare and not the actual text - that way if you want to change the text of the status later on, you don't have to update all of your queries.